# New array from multidimensional array - url parsing

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, url-parameters, urlparse

I have the following URL: *myexample.com/**?city=Miami***

and a large array (23k)

```
$e = $_GET["city"];


$myArray = array
(
array ("Miami","Florida"),
array ("Key West","Florida"),
array ("NOLA", "Luisiana"),
array ("Baton Rouge","Luisiana")
);
```

I'm looking for a solution to dynamically create a new array of cities that matches the state of the city in the URL, and echo all the cities from that state.

In other words:

if myexample.com/?city=NOLA, I would like to echo "Baton Rouge" and "NOLA" (from Luisiana)
if myexample.com/?city=Miami, echo "Key West" and "Miami" (from Florida)
etc.

There are quite a few similar questions answered already ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903358/create-new-array-using-values-from-multidimensional-array-sharing-values), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447923/how-to-filter-a-two-dimensional-array-by-value), but looping is not one of strengths (beginner).

Thank you.

EDIT1:

```
$resArray = array();
foreach($myArray as $arr) {
    if(in_array($e, $arr)) 
        $resArray[] = $arr;
}
print_r($resArray);
```

Result: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Miami [1] => Florida ) )

Comment: And what do you want from us? Write you the codez?

Comment: Show us what have you tried till now? If you are expecting someone to answer and write code for you, not the right place.

Comment: What I tried is to check if $e exist in $myArray and add it to a new array. (see edit 1)

Comment: It also might be better if you show what you get (your url params), what you want (how the result should look like) and what you tried.

Comment: @u_mulder  Not really, just  the right direction. Perhaps my array is not built the same way as I've seen in other examples. I searched for similar solutions on here and Google (up to the 150th result) using different search terms, and the code I have so far is either an error or not showing what I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would restructure your `myArray` in something like the following:

```
$stateAndCities = [
    "Florida" => ["Miami","Key West"],
    "Luisiana" => ["NOLA", "Baton Rouge"]
];
```

after that you can better handle the input and give an easier output

```
$city = $_GET["city"];
$resultCities = [];
$resultState = "";

// Loop over all states with their cities
foreach($stateAndCities as $state => $cities) {
    if(in_array($city, $cities)){ // if the given $city is in the $cities?
        $resultCities = $cities;
        $resultState = $state;
        break;
    }
}

if(!empty($resultState) && !empty($resultCities)){ // ensure that the city was found in any state
    echo $resultState;
    print_r($resultCities);
}
```

**(the code is not tested!)**

**Manual:**

http://php.net/in_array

http://php.net/empty

Comment: Thank you, it work's. What I was after is the last part where I added: 

    echo "Other cities in ".$state.":<br />";

 for($x=0;$x<count($resultCities);$x++){
  echo "<br />".$resultCities[$x]."<br />";
 }
}